# Can't allocate an array dynamically of size 10

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

I'm trying to dynamically allocate an array of size 10. But when I print the elements of the array, I get 
value of 8 elements. (I'm working on the editor provided by hackerrank.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *s = malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
    scanf("%[^\n]", s);
    int* freq = (int*)calloc(10,sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(freq);i++)
        printf("%d ",freq[i]);
    }
```

Expected output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The output I'm getting:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Why am I not getting the expected output?

Comment: `sizeof(freq)` is the size of the pointer, not what it points to, You *know* the length of the array, you just passed `10` to `calloc`.

Comment: `sizeof` returns the size of the pointer itself in bytes, not the amount of array elements it points to. There's no way to get the size of a dynamically allocated array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof(freq)` will return the size of `int *` in bytes in your machine which happens to be 8. Just use `i < 10`.